# How to automatically expand folder in file manager

Tags: window-manager

How to expand the folder automatically especially when I want to transfer a file from other location..

Currently I have to perform many operations such as get them to home and then transfer to a folder , then transfer to sub folder etc..

Comment: You mean in same Nautilus window from current folder to subfolder? Or in case 2 or couple of open window? In case couple, do you review case when one window minimized?

Comment: Open the source folder, right-click on the file, choose `Copy` or `Cut`, navigate to the destination folder, right-click and choose `Insert` .. that is what to do.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you mean with "expand a folder"? What is precisely the issue you are having?